# Import statment in Scala Play Framework doesn't work

Tags: templates, scala, playframework

I have the following code:

```
@(data: model.FrontPageData, list:List[model.FrontPageData])(
  implicit
  params:play.mvc.Scope.Params,
  flash:play.mvc.Scope.Flash,
  errors:Map[String,play.data.validation.Error]
)

@import controllers._
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>some title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 ....
```

And Play Framework returns this error:

> The file /app/views/Application/frontPageEditor.scala.html could not
>   be compiled.  Error raised is : illegal start of simple expression

on line `@↓import controllers._`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is parsing bug on windows systems, based on play framework support response. 
On linux systems it works.
Hope they will fix it soon on windows.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on linux and Playframework 2.3.7 (

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `import` statements from a template in the middle of the code, it's a limitation in Play templates. You must put them at the beginning of the template, as per [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/modules/scala-0.9.1/templates#Importstatements).

You can use fully qualified names though. In you case, if you have controller XController, do:

```
controllers.XController.method()
```

to access it

(Edited after comments)

Comment: But why then it is allowed in documentation? http://www.playframework.org/modules/scala-0.9.1/templates#Importstatements

Comment: You are right,t he import issue is in Java, not Scala. But documentation reads: "You can import whatever you want at the begining of your template (or of a sub template)" Your issue is that your are importing in the middle of the template.

Comment: I've tried to place it as first line and after parameter list - result is the same! Have you tired to use import statment?

Comment: @yura Can't test it right now, I don't have Play env here. I would say that your best bet is to simply use the fully qualified name. As per documentation import in first lines should work, if not you may raise a bug against Play Scala module. 
To be honest I never use imports, I always use qualified names in templates as I started with Play using Java and there it works that way.